# Randomly pick a memory location in an Array?

Tags: vb.net, arrays

I know this may sound like a weird question to ask but I would like to know how to have the code randomly pick a memory location in an Array without having it filled, perferably in VB.NET

Thinking of the logic, I was thinking

```
Dim random As Random
Dim tic(2, 2) As String


random.Next(tic(2,2))
```

Would putting the array as a parameter would randomly pick a memory location in an array? Yeah I really don't know what I'm talking about so I really need to be led on the right path if possible.

Comment: I'm not quite following....can you elaborate?

Comment: Sure I'll try. the 2-d array is a 3x3 square. Instead of randomly filling in a value within the 3x3 square, I want the code to randomly pick a square for me and leave it as that.

Comment: All you need to two is generate two random numbers then ;-)

Comment: personally I'd choose 1,1 :-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just looking for a random index for the array to fill it with data?

```
Dim x = random.Next(2)
Dim y = random.Next(2)

tic(x,y) = "Some value"
```

Comment: The index is already set to (2,2) but if I set the index value to a random variable as what you posted and set it to variable, that should work.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
Dim random as New Random
Dim tic(2, 2) As String

' Use UBound instead of 2, if your array may be a different size.
Dim i As Integer = random.Next (0, 2)
Dim j As Integer = random.Next (0, 2)

Console.WriteLine (tic(i,j))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you could do it in CSharp...

```
    Random random = new Random();
    int len1 = 2;
    int len2 = 2;

    string[,] tic = new string[len1, len2];
    string nextString = tic[random.Next() % len1, random.Next() % len2];
```